# How to reference an array element in ObjectiveC when that element is buried in an object hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I have having a hard time with ObjectiveC syntax.
I have an array that is buried within an object hierarchy and I can't figure out how to reference elements from the array.

Please see my object in the screenshot below:  link provided.

https://skitch.com/aibkwik/rqunh/fullscreen

the element I am trying to reference is the "school" - whose value is "Freedom High".

Can someone provide me with the appropriate reference syntax?
I've tried things like:

```
*nsstringptr = [cellValue.courses objectAtIndex:0 school];
```

- I know I know - I'm a noob.

But Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is your dCourse object's superclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *school = [[[cellValue courses] objectAtIndex:0] school];
```

Comment: Ole similarly, I am trying to alloc an array that is deeply embedded in an object hierarchy.  The top object instance is call "thisYear" and it has an array in it called "courses".  "courses" also contains, among other things, an array called scoreCatetories.How would you initialize and add an object to the "scoreCategories" array?    I've tried numerous things, including:                                                                                  [thisYear courses] scoreCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[[[thisYear courses] scoreCategories] addObject:tmpSC];

Comment: Well, you say `courses` is an array, so you must select an object in the array to work on: `[[[thisYear courses] objectAtIndex:0] setScoreCategories:[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]]; [[[[thisYear courses] objectAtIndex:0] scoreCategories] addObject:tmpSC];`. Needless to say that this is a really unelegant way of doing this. You should really read some beginner literature.